# i just want to add the name john to the end of the vertical list but i dont know how use basic function no imports please

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to add john to the list but i don't know how.
Note the spaces in between the names dont have a comma it only has value 0 unlike normal list.

[here is a picture of the names list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTS9x.png)

I expect the output to include john at the end of the list.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question, pasting your code and output verbatim. Images of code are discouraged. ([See why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).)

Comment: Your question is still unclear. My assumption is that you have a list of names in the file and you want to append a new entry in that? Am I right?

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin list method in python exactly for doing what you want, called .append().

Let's say you have this:

```
a = ["maria", "jack", "dave"]
b = "john"
```

To insert john to the a list, all you have to do is:

```
a.append(b)
```

You might also call the appended value directly, as below:

```
a.append("john") #supposing your list is in a variable named a
```

The append will always include the variable/value at the end of the list.

You might have some good insights reading the docs also:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html